# The differences between Appendix register and programme register in XCVM registers

Tags: xcm

**3.1 Programme**

Of type Vec, initialized to the value of the Original Programme.

Expresses the currently executing programme of instructions for the XCVM. This gets potentially changed after either the final instruction is executed or an error occurs.

**3.5 Appendix**

Of type Vec, initialized to the empty list.

Expresses any code which should run following the current programme. When a programme reaches the end successfully, or after an error where the Error Handler is empty, this register is cleared and its contents used to replace the Programme Register.

*For example in a simulation of xcm instruction executions. Lets say there are 4 instructions, The programme register holds all 4 instructions and appendix only holds the executed instruction or?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions you reference are pretty good.

The Programme Register holds the currently executing programme of instructions for the XCVM.

The Appendix Register holds the code you want to execute after the Programme Register has executed all the instructions in the Programme Register or after the error handler has completed.

> This gets potentially changed after either the final instruction is executed or an error occurs.

This is because what is in the Appendix (or in the Error Handler), replaces what is in the Programme Register once the Programme Register executed all instructions or hits an error and there is an Error Handler.

You can use the `SetAppendix(Xcm<call>)` instruction to set the Appendix Register.

So in your example, if the Programme Register holds 4 instructions. Each instruction will be executed and when complete, if there is an instruction inside the Appendix Register, then that will be executed. Or if while executing one of the instructions in the Programme Register, if there is an error and there is an Error Handler, that will be executed. Then whatever instruction is in the Appendix will be executed.

✌️